# PHP - Group array by array of keys

Tags: php

I have been going over this for days, and Stack Overflow is my last resort.

I was wondering how I can get from the left structure to the right structure:

```
From this:                                        To this:
-----------------------------------               -----------------------------------
| R1   | NULL,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6   |               | NULL        | T1,T2,T5          |
| R2   | T1,T2,T3                 |               | R1          | NULL              |
| R3   | T1,T2,T3                 |   -------->   | R1,R2,R3,R4 | T1,T2             |
| R4   | T1,T2                    |               | R1,R2,R3    | T3                |
| NULL | T1,T2,T5                 |               | R1          | T4,T5,T6          |
-----------------------------------               -----------------------------------
```

### Notes/rules:

- If value or category is `NULL`, create a separate group for it.
- First, try to make groups with as much as possible R's (prop: value). So it results in [R1,R2,R3,R4 | T1,T2] instead of [R1,R2,R3 | T1,T2,T3]
- I'm not looking for a copy-paste answer, but I am breaking my head over this for days and I would love some suggestions how to properly do this in PHP.

### In PHP

```
$input = [
  [
    'value' => null,
    'categories' => ['T1', 'T2', 'T5']
  ],
  [
    'value' => 'R1',
    'categories' => [NULL, 'T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4', 'T5', 'T6']
  ],
  [
    'value' => 'R2',
    'categories' => ['T1', 'T2', 'T3']
  ],
  [
    'value' => 'R3',
    'categories' => ['T1', 'T2', 'T3']
  ],
  [
    'value' => 'R4',
    'categories' => ['T1', 'T2']
  ]
]

// DESIRED OUTPUT
$input = [
  [
    'values' => [NULL],
    'categories' => ['T1', 'T2', 'T5']
  ],
  [
    'values' => ['R1'],
    'categories' => [NULL]
  ],
  [
    'values' => ['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4'],
    'categories' => ['T1', 'T2']
  ],
  [
    'values' => ['R1', 'R2', 'R3'],
    'categories' => ['T3']
  ],
  [
    'value' => 'R1',
    'categories' => ['T4', 'T5', 'T6']
  ]
]
```

Comment: it is not clear how you convert the array. What are the conversion rules/steps?

Comment: I think I understand your idea, but the output could be in this format: ```$input = [ ['values' => 'T1', 'categories' => ['R1', 'R2', 'R3'], ...]```?

Answer (score 1):

The logic here is not to work by `values (Rx)`, but by `categories (Tx)`.

If you filter the input on :

- is value `Rx` or category `Tx` null?
- by catagory `Tx => Rx`

you can collect all `Rx` for a given `Tx`. You end up (excluding the nulls) with an array where the values `Rx` are sorted by category `Tx`. For instance:

```
T1 => [ R1, R2, R3, R4 ]
T2 => [ R1, R2, R3, R4 ]
T3 => [ R1, R2, R3 ]
```

Now you must group the array by `Rx` ranges, so that all the `[R1, R2, R3, R4 ]`  are joined together in one result array:

`[ R1, R2, R3, R4 ] => [ T1, T2 ]`

The trick here is to make `[ R1, R2, R3, R4 ]` a string so it can function as key (array-keys can't be arrays themselves). Make sure to **sort the array** first! Then collect all the `Tx` per string, also saving the actual `Rx` array:

```
R1R2R3R4 => [ values => [ R1, R2, R3, R4 ], categories => [ T1, T2 ] ]
R1R2R3   => [ values => [ R1, R2, R3 ], categories => [ T3 ] ]
```

Use that array together with the nulls to create the result.

```
//set some arrays
$nulls=[];
$categories=[];
$tmp=[];

//loop $INPUT
foreach($input as $inp){

    // VALUE (Rx) = NULL :: put in $nulls
    if($inp['value']===NULL){
        $nulls[]=['values'=>[NULL],'categories'=>$inp['categories']];
        continue;
        }
    // ELSE use VALUE (Rx)
    $Rx=$inp['value'];
    
    //loop CATEGORIES (Tx)
    foreach($inp['categories'] as $Tx){
        // CATEGORY (Tx) = NULL :: put in $nulls
        if($Tx===NULL){
            $nulls[]=['values'=>[$Rx],'categories'=>[null]];
            continue;
            }
        // push $categories [ Tx ] [] => VALUE (Rx) 
        $categories[$Tx][]=$Rx;
        }
    }

//sort $categories Tx => [ Rx, Rx, Rx ]
foreach($categories as $Tx=>$Rx){
    // create a KEY STRING R1R2R3R4.
    // Make sure to first SORT the values, so the order is consistent!
    sort($Rx);
    $string=implode('',$Rx);
    // if not exists $tmp [ KEY STRING ]
    // create $tmp [ KEY STRING ] => [ values=>[ Rx] , categories[ ] ]
    if(!isset($tmp[$string]))
        $tmp[$string]=[
            'values'=>$Rx,
            'categories'=>[]
            ];
    // push $tmp [  KEY STRING ][ categories ][] = Tx
    $tmp[$string]['categories'][]=$Tx;
    }

// create $result
// $nulls has either values or is empty array. So we can always use it.
$result=$nulls;
// loop TMP, adding [ values=>[ Rx] , categories[ Tx ] ]
foreach($tmp as $v){
    $result[]=[
            'values'=>$v['values'],
            'categories'=>$v['categories']
            ];
    }
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I'm going to try this out and see if this logic will work for me. Many thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome. It gives the desired output, but please do test with different values as well. If it fails, I'll hear from you.